# Not able to map a new column in existing dataframe (html based)

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

we have a SES service that stores outlook emails in html format and once can access them via API links, now through python i am trying to store the important values which are there in the email, i am able to store the html table from api in python data frame but not being able to add a new column. what could be the reason ?

[image]

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
from operator import itemgetter
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


with urlopen('https://pv-ft-marketdata-store.ihsmvals-dev.com/email/search?asof=2022-07-20') as resp:
    json_data = json.load(resp)

json_data.sort(key=itemgetter("processed"), reverse=True)
for i in range(0,len(json_data)):
    if re.findall("Morgan Stanley Systematic Strategies Daily Level",json_data[i]["subject"]):
        key = json_data[i]["key"]
        subject = json_data[i]["subject"]
        Date = re.findall(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}',json_data[i]["subject"])
print(subject)
print(key)
print(Date)
#("Morgan Stanley Systematic Strategies Daily Level"))
URL = "https://pv-ft-marketdata-store.ihsmvals-dev.com/email/" + key + "/data/html"

html = requests.get(URL).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[-1]


Pkey = {'MSUSDSP5': 71763307, 'MSUSSPVP': 76366654,'MSCBICCO':137292386, 'MSCBWGSP':151971418, 'MSCBBGEC':151971419, 'MSUSEVHI':152547427, 'MSCBCTAD':152547426}

df['Pkey'] = df['Ticker'].map(Pkey)
print(df.head().to_dict())
```

[image]

Comment: your column names are `0` and `1` at the moment. your header are in the first row at index `0`. Try this: `df_list = pd.read_html(html, header=[0])`

Comment: i was trying (html, index=False) but using header=[0] able to remove the first now but i am getting a new error now ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (7)

Comment: index=False is no valid argument in that function. Did you have a look at the documentation? with header=[0] you didn't "remove" the first line, it is just used as the names to your columns. in which line of code you get that ValueError now ?

Comment: df['Pkey'] = df['Ticker'].map(Pkey) in this line of code

Comment: could you please run `df.head().to_dict()` and post here?

Comment: what is `df = df_list[-1]` supposed to do ? maybe it is better if you post the result of `df_list = pd.read_html(html, header=[0]); df_list.head().to_dict()`. please add that to your question.

Comment: getting the following error now - AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: hm ok, can't open the link. back to the first attempt. `pd.read_html()` returned a list of `df's`. `df = df_list[-1]`returns the last df in that list. please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73096818/edit) your question and add the data of `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: i guess df.head only works in Jupiter notebook, isnt it ? i am using pycharm

Comment: no, it didn't work because df_list isn't a dataframe. `df` is a dataframe and df.head() should work

Comment: i have added the result of print(df.head().to_dict()) in my original query for your review

Comment: ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (7)
{'Ticker': {0: 'MSUSDSP5', 1: 'MSUSSPVP', 2: 'MSCBICCO', 3: 'MSCBWGSP', 4: 'MSCBBGEC'}, 'Level': {0: 220.17, 1: 323.64, 2: 225.8, 3: 150.57, 4: 128.72}}

Comment: hm ok, `df['Pkey'] = df['Ticker'].map(Pkey)` is working fine for me with the data you added to your question and the dictionary Pkey. It should work now. Maybe close everything and start again, then let the code run from beginning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246715/discussion-between-rahul-vaidya-and-rabinzel).

Comment: i have tried in a fresh version but still the same error